# Allocated memory in multiple cmocka unit tests

Tags: c, cmocka

I'm trying to unit test some source code using cmocka. Basically the (relevant) source code looks similar to Source.c.

The unit test calls each function separately. When testing the *Add()* function this function will eventually call *util_malloc()* (this function normally checks for 0 size before malloc) which is wrapped by the unit test. In the wrapped function *__wrap_util_malloc()*, in Wrappers.c, first the size is checked for expected after which malloc is used to allocate memory.

Next the *Remove()* function is tested in which the previously allocated memory gets freed.

When running the test cmocka returns with the following failures:

```
<failure><![CDATA[Blocks allocated... project_path/wrappers.c:46:  note: block 00341e58 allocated here ERROR: Add_Test leaked 1 block(s) ]]></failure>
```

and

```
<failure><![CDATA[EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION occurred at 004060af.
To debug in Visual Studio... [...]
]]></failure>
```

For now I've added a *Remove()* call at the end of the *Add_Test()* function (and an *Add()* at the beginning of *Remove_Test()*). This seems to fix the issue. Judging from this, one should free all allocated memory in each separate unit test.

Now my questions:

1. Is it possible to use allocated memory in multiple unit test?
2. What would be the best way to solve this?

### Source.c:

```c
static ST_SOME_STRUCT GlobStruct;

void Add()
{
    GlobStruct = util_malloc(sizeof(ST_SOME_STRUCT));
}

void Remove()
{
    util_free(&GlobStruct);    
}

void DoStuff()
{
    //Do stuff using the global structure GlobStruct
}
```

### Unit_test.c:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
const struct CMUnitTest Test[] =
   {
      cmocka_unit_test(Add_Test),      
      cmocka_unit_test(Remove_Test),
   };
   cmocka_set_message_output( CM_OUTPUT_XML );
   return cmocka_run_group_tests( Test, NULL, NULL );
}

static void Add_Test (void** state)
{
   expect_value(__wrap_util_malloc, size, sizeof(ST_SOME_STRUCT ));
   Add();
}

static void Remove_Test (void** state)
{
   expect_not_value(__wrap_util_free, memory, cast_ptr_to_largest_integral_type(NULL));
   Remove();
}
```

### Wrappers.c:

```
void *__wrap_util_malloc(int size)
{
    check_expected(size);
    return malloc(size);
}

void __wrap_util_free(void *memory)
{
    check_expected_ptr(memory);
    free(memory);
}
```

Comment: I don't know about cmocka, but generally a testcase is more than just one function call. If you have function with internal states you have to call it multiple times to test it thoroughly. In the same spirit you may need to add setup (pre) or clean up (post) test code to get the whole test. So if you allocate something, make sure that your clean up code frees it and vice versa, allocate something that your `remove()` function has to free (without using `add()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running tests using `cmocka_run_group_tests`, cmocka will still run individual setup or teardown functions for each test, along with its internal functions which check if you forgot to free blocks (hence the message `Add_Test leaked 1 block(s)`). After each test, cmocka will also free any blocks allocated inside that test before running the next one.

Common approach is that each of your tests should perform cleanup of anything allocated within that single test. If you want to initialize shared state at the beginning of the group test, specify group setup/teardown functions to initialize shared state (which will be passed to each unit test as a parameter), or use test setup/teardown functions to be called before each test.

As always, it's a bad idea (and makes testing harder) to have global shared variables. Your `Add` and `Remove` functions (and all other dealing with this object) should accept a pointer to the struct containing the data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll have a try with setup and cleanup functions. The global variable is actual a linked list but I've simplified the code for this question. Anyway, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Maartn: it's not relevant what the global is, you should pass it as a parameter (like in [this implementation](https://github.com/skorks/c-linked-list/blob/master/linkedlist.c), or [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/marodrig/10799703), or [this](https://gist.github.com/ardrabczyk/1cdc413b9eaa9a9a0c4be71d3fc9bc37), or practically any implementation you can find). A rule of thumb for making code, regardless of the language is: if you are mutating a global variable, you are probably doing something wrong.